# A simple way to read TXT config files in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, config

this question seems to be already asked but I did not find any convenient solution for my case.
I have the following TXT config file to read in C++:

```
--CONFIGURATION 1 BEGIN--

IP address:                          192.168.1.145
Total track length [m]:              1000
Output rate [1/s]:                   10
Time [s]:                            1
Running mode (0=OFF 1=ON):           1
Total number of attempts:            10
Mode (0=OFF, 1=BEG, 2=ADV, 3=PROF):  1

--Available only for Administrators--

Variable 1 [mV]:                     2600
Gain 1 [mV]:                         200
Position tracking (0=OFF 1=ON):      0
Coefficient 2 [V]:                   5.2

--CONFIGURATION 1 END--

--CONFIGURATION 2 BEGIN--

Max track distance [m]:             10000
Internal track length [m]:          100
Offset distance [mV]:               1180
GAIN bias [mV]:                     200
Number of track samples:            1000
Resolution (1 or 2) [profile]:      1

--CONFIGURATION 2 END--
```

I need to store only the value at the end of each line that could be a string (in the case of the IP address), an int, a float or a bool inside a struct. In C there is a very simple solution, I read each single line using an expression as follows:

```
if(!fscanf(fp, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %d\n", &(settings->trackLength))) {

    printf("Invalid formatting of configuration file. Check trackLength.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

The %*s allows to discard the label of the line and the spaces before the interested value. I use fgets to skip the empty lines or the titles. This way works also in C++. Is it good to leave my code as is or do you see a better and simple way to do this in C++?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Read entire lines, then parse them. Also, avoid legacy C stuff (such as `scanf` etc) like plague in C++.

Comment: `/n` at the end of `scanf` format string does not do what you think it does.

Comment: First of all, thank you hyde for your comment. Yes I have already seen this way but why should I replace a single (and simple) line of code that already does what I want with more lines of code to do the same thing? Isn't there a single expression in C++ that does what requested?  Thank you again.

Comment: It very much looks like your `fscanf` is plain wrong in your example code (at least it does not match your input file). For starters it does not read lines at all, it reads 4 words and then tries to read&parse an integer. Which highlights how `scanf` is easy to get wrong -> use something which makes it harder to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: this doesn't look like standard configuration file. Usually it is a `ini` file or `xml` or `json` files are used for this purpose and there is many ready solution to read/write such config. I never seen format you have presented, so probably it will be hard to find ready solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also in C++ it is easy to split a line. I have already provided several answers here on SO on how to split a string. Anyway, I will explain it here in detail and for your special case. I also provide a full working example later.

We use the basic functionality of `std::getline` which can read a complete line or the line up to a given character. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Let us take an example. If the text is stored in a `std::string` we will first put it into a `std::istringstream`. Then we can use `std::getline` to extract the data from the `std::istringstream`. That is always the standard approach. First, read the complete line from a file using `std::getline`, then, put it in a `std::istringstream` again, to be able extract the parts of the string again with `std::getline`.

If a source line looks like that:

```
Time [s]:                            1
```

We can obsserve that we have several parts:

- An identifier "Time [s]",
- a colon, which acts as a separator,
- one or more spaces and
- the value "1"

So, we could write something like this:

```
std::string line{};  // Here we will store a complete line read from the source file
std::getline(configFileStream, line);  // Read a complete line from the source file
std::istringstream iss{ line };  // Put line into a istringstream for further extraction

std::string id{};  // Here we will store the target value "id"
std::string value{};   // Here we will store the target "value"
std::getline(iss, id, ':');  // Read the ID, get read of the colon
iss >> std::ws;  // Skip all white spaces
std::getline(iss, value);  // Finally read the value
```

So, that is a lot of text. You may have heard that you can chain IO-Operations, like in `std::cout << a << b << c`. This works, because the << operation always returns a reference to the given stream. And the same is true for `std::getline`. And because it does this, we can use nested statements. Meaning, we can put the second `std::getline` at this parameter position (actually the first paramater) where it expects a `std::istream`. If we follow this approach consequently then we can write the nested statement:

```
std::getline(std::getline(iss, id, ':') >> std::ws, value);
```

Ooops, whats going on here? Let's analyze from inside out. First the operation `std::getline(iss, id, ':')` extracts a string from the `std::istringstream` and assign it to variable "id". OK, understood. Remember: std::getline, will return a reference to the given stream. So, then the above reduced statement is

```
std::getline(iss >> std::ws, value)
```

Next, `iss >> std::ws` will be evaluated and will result in eating up all not necessary white spaces. And guess what, it will return a refernce to the gievn stream "iss".

Statement looks now like:

```
std::getline(iss, value)
```

And this will read the value. Simple.

But, we are not finished yet. Of course std::getline will return again "iss". And in the below code, you will see something like

```
if (std::getline(std::getline(iss, id, ':') >> std::ws, value))
```

which will end up as `if (iss)`. So, we use `iss` as a boolean expression? Why does this work and what does it do? It works, because the `bool operator` of the `std::stream` is overwritten and returns, if the state is OK or has a failure. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) for an explanation. Always check the result of any IO-operation.

And last but not least, we need to explain the `if` statement with initializer. You can read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

I can write

```
if (std::string id{}, value{}; std::getline(std::getline(iss, id, ':') >> std::ws, value)) {
```

which is the similar to

```
std::string id{}, value{}; 
if (std::getline(std::getline(iss, id, ':') >> std::ws, value)) {
```

But the first example has the advantage that the defined variables will be only visible within the `if`-statements scope. So, we "scope" the variable as narrow as possible.

You should try to do that as often as possible. You should also always check the return state of an IO-operation by applying `if` to a stream-operation, as shown above.

The complete program for reading everything will then just be a few lines of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    // Open config file and check, if it coul be opened
    if (std::ifstream configFileStream{ "r:\\config.txt" }; configFileStream) {

        // Here we wills tore the resulting config data
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> configData;

        // Read all lines of the source file
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(configFileStream, line); )
        {
            // If the line contains a colon, we treat it as valid data
            if (if (line.find(':') != std::string::npos)) {

                // Split data in line into an id and a value part and save it
                std::istringstream iss{ line };
                if (std::string id{}, value{}; std::getline(std::getline(iss, id, ':') >> std::ws, value)) {

                    // Add config data to our map
                    configData[id] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        // Some debug output
        for (const auto& [id, value] : configData)
            std::cout << "ID: " << std::left << std::setw(35) << id << " Value: " << value << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open config file for reading\n";

    return 0;
}
```

For this example I store the ids and values in a map, so that they can be accessed easily.